# Email system for generic adresses: alias, mailing-list or other?

Tags: ubuntu, email, ubuntu-14.04

As I am not very familiar with the email system, I'll try to describe my needs rather than ask how to do it with a specific feature.

I'd like to define a few generic addresses under my own domain, for example `support@mydomain.com` and `bugs@mydomain.com`.

When a user (let's say `bob@bobsmail.com`) sends a message to `support@mydomain.com`, I'd like a predefined list of people (let's say `support_alice@othermail.com` and `support_carol@othermail.com`) to receive Bob's message.

I'd like the message title to be prefixed with `[Support]`, and the message header filled so that if `support_carol@mydomain.com` uses "Reply-all" on this message, the reply is sent to both `bob@bobsmail.com` and `support@mydomain.com`. Ability to customize the message's body would be great, but not mandatory.

When the sender is part of the list, he should not receive the message. In my example, if `support_carol@othermail.com` uses "Reply-all", the reply will only be received by `bob@bobsmail.com` and `support_alice@othermail.com`.

Obviously, spam and viruses should be annihilated....

This will be running on an Ubuntu 14.04 system. Paid-for software is not an option, and RAM usage must be kept low.

Any pointers and opinion greatly appreciated ! Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need a mailing list software, but we don't do product recommendations.

Comment: I wasn't looking for products recommendations, but rather what were the suited concepts and building blocks to research to fulfill my goal. If this question was more suited to superuser, all apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a full blown MLM (mailing list management) system like Sympa or Mailman but for your requirements (as I understand them) a set of aliases and some procmail scripts would probably do the trick.